# Dropdown jumps on focus when scrolling

Tags: javascript, scroll, focus

I am doing a custom dropdown and have done most of it including all kinds of navigation. But I have one issue.

My markup is like this

```
<div class="cont">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <label>item1</label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <label>item2</label>
</div>
```

when you click arrow down, the next input is focused and the container scrolls (`has overflow-y: scroll`).
The scrolling works, and the next item is selected, but everytime it jumps to 0 and then scrolls to element.

I am pretty sure it is the focus that does this, but I have tried all kinds of stuff to avoid the jump.

The javascript part that does the scroling:

```
var step = 34 // get height of label    
easy_drop.$result.on('keydown', '.filterdrp_list_item', function (e) {
    // console.log('5')     

    if (e.keyCode === 40) { // Down                                     
        e.preventDefault();

        $("[data-filterresult]").stop().animate({
            scrollTop: "+=" + step + "px"
        }, 1);

        $(this).nextAll('.filterdrp_list_item')
            .not('[style="display: none;"]')
            .first()
            .focus(); 
    }
```

Comment: You might want to include the input into the label. Can you show us more of the jQuery so we can understand more?

Comment: jep
I have added the javascript that does the arrow down event.

Comment: Can you reproduce that in a JSFiddle ?

Comment: Actually if I could just imitate a TAB key event, when doing kydown, that would do the trick

Comment: I thought I couldn't reproduce the issue but actually I can see what is happening. Is it like this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4j9omw08/9/) ?

Comment: exactly.. This is so anoying. Thanks for making the fiddle. So I wonder if you can focus a checkbox, without using focus ?

Comment: I updated the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/4j9omw08/12/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I managed to fix it.
The reason why it was jumping was because, all my inputs were at the top, because they were absolute position. Therefore I wrapped all items i spans, so a span would inlude first input and them label.

By doing these changes, I also did not need the scrolltop javascript, because native html worked fine

That helped.
Of cause I also had to do changes in CSS and JS, for the new changes.